# ERROR request for member 'suivant' in '* listeNote', which is of pointer type 'listenote {aka notes*}' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have the exercice below to do :

> We want to manage the grades of our students. Students are identified by their student number. They have a name and a surname. This information is stored in a linked list, each element of which also includes an avg field for the student's average and an eval field which is a pointer to his list of notes. The list of notes for each student is also a linked list whose head is the eval field of the student cell

This is my code, but i get the errors :

-Users\lenovo\Desktop\exercice final.cpp    [Error] request for member 'suivant' in '* listeNote', which is of pointer type 'listenote {aka notes*}' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)

-Users\lenovo\Desktop\exercice final.cpp    [Error] request for member 'suivant' in '* listeNote', which is of pointer type 'listenote {aka notes*}' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)

-Users\lenovo\Desktop\exercice final.cpp    [Error] request for member 'val' in '* student', which is of pointer type 'liste_et {aka etudiants*}' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)

-Users\lenovo\Desktop\exercice final.cpp    [Error] request for member 'suivant' in '* listeEtudiant', which is of pointer type 'liste_et {aka etudiants*}' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)

-Users\lenovo\Desktop\exercice final.cpp    [Error] request for member 'suivant' in '* listeEtudiant', which is of pointer type 'liste_et {aka etudiants*}' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)

Could you please help me to figure out the issue ??

Thank youu

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
 int coef; 
 float nt;  
 }note_matiere;

//Definition de Note :
struct notes{
note_matiere nm;
struct notes* suivant;
};
typedef struct notes* listenote;

typedef struct {
 int ne; 
 char nom[20];
 char prenom[20];
 float moy;
}etudiant;

//Definition de Etudiant :
struct etudiants
{etudiant etd;
listenote eval;
struct etudiants *suivant;
};
typedef struct etudiants* liste_et;

int main ()
{ int i,j; 
liste_et etuds[30];
listenote* listeNote=NULL;
liste_et* listeEtudiant=NULL;
for(i==0;i<5;i++){
liste_et* student=(liste_et*)malloc(sizeof(liste_et)); 
printf("donner le nom de l'etudiant \n");
scanf("%u",etuds[i]->etd.nom); getchar();
printf("donner le prenom de l'etudiant \n");
scanf("%u",etuds[i]->etd.prenom);
printf("donner le numero de l'etudiant \n");
scanf("%d",&etuds[i]->etd.ne);  
listenote notes[10];
 for(j==0;j<3;j++){
 listenote* lsnotes=(listenote*)malloc(sizeof(listenote));
printf("donner la note \n");
scanf("%f",&notes[i]->nm.nt);
printf("donner le coeff \n");
scanf("%d",&notes[i]->nm.coef);
if(i==0) listeNote=lsnotes ;
else if(i==4) listeNote->suivant=NULL;
else listeNote->suivant=lsnotes;    
 }
 student->val=listeNote;
if(i==0) listeEtudiant=student ;
else if(i==4) listeEtudiant->suivant=NULL;
else listeEtudiant>suivant=student;
}
return 0;
        } ```
````

Comment: Hint: `listeNote` is a pointer to a pointer to the structure. `(*listeNote)->suivant` will be syntactically valid (I'm not sure about semantics).

Comment: `typedef struct notes* listenote;  listenote* listeNote=NULL;  listeNote->suivant=NULL;` something odd?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\[ERROR \]request for member in which is of pointer type maybe you meant to use -> ?) in C BST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54143304/error-request-for-member-in-which-is-of-pointer-type-maybe-you-meant-to-use)